# Getting "Authorization has been denied for this request" after integrating Swagger Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a project on ASP web API. Recently i have integrated swashbuckle swagger into the project. But every time i try the api call via swagger i get following response:

```
{
  "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

This is the request header:

```
{
   "date": "Fri, 11 Mar 2016 03:53:41 GMT",
   "www-authenticate": "Bearer",
   "x-sourcefiles": "=?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcaXRzYW5cZG9jdW1lbnRzXHZpc3VhbCBzdHVkaW8gMjAxM1xQcm9qZWN0c1xMZWFybldlYkFQSVxMZWFybldlYkFQSVxhcGlcVmFsdWVz?=",
   "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0",
   "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
   "content-length": "61",
   "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
```

My startup.cs looks like following:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

If i want to view the api calls via default, everything is fine. Can any body help.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The message and **response** header says it all. You probably have an `[Authorize]` attribute on the endpoint.

Comment: @Nkosi, i figured it out before, thanks for the confirmation. Appreciate it.